# loading data local to hive database facing issue

Tags: hive, bigdata, hiveql

```
hive>LOAD DATA INPATH '/hadoop/abc/POC2_Setup/input/warr2_claims_5441F.csv' OVERWRITE INTO TABLE baumuster_pre_analysi_text;
```

> FAILED: SemanticException Line 1:17 Invalid path
>   ''/hadoop/abc/POC2_Setup/input/warr2_claims_5441F.csv'': No files
>   matching path
>   hdfs://localhost:9000/hadoop/abc/POC2_Setup/input/warr2_claims_5441F.csv

Comment: Do you have the file - hdfs://localhost:9000/hadoop/abc/POC2_Setup/input/warr2_claims_5441F.csv. Any chance you have the file under /user/hadoop as opposed to /hadoop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we are loading from local file system, we need to use the keyword "local" as below,

LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH 'your local file path' OVERWRITE INTO TABLE your-hive-table;

If loading from HDFS,

LOAD DATA INPATH 'your hdfs file path' OVERWRITE INTO TABLE your-hive-table;

Answer (score 0):

If you are loading the data from local then you have to mention  `LOCAL` .

`hive>LOAD LOCAL DATA INPATH '/hadoop/abc/POC2_Setup/input/warr2_claims_5441F.csv' OVERWRITE INTO TABLE baumuster_pre_analysi_text;`

and if your default directory is not set as local then you have to mention `file:/` before the path.

Answer (score 0):

To load data from local machine you can use the following command:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH '/hadoop/abc/POC2_Setup/input/warr2_claims_5441F.csv' OVERWRITE INTO TABLE baumuster_pre_analysi_text;
```